# How to merge only the missing rows

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have this code.

However I got an exception in the merge line:

```
Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.
```

I would like a simple way, that it merges the missing rows only, if there are rows that already exist, it shouldn't try to copy them

Thanks

```
// Init
UC010_WizardStepBusinessParkDataSet dataSet = new UC010_WizardStepBusinessParkDataSet();
View_BuildingModule_UC010_BusinessPark_Wizard_GetBusinessParkData vwBusPark = new View_BuildingModule_UC010_BusinessPark_Wizard_GetBusinessParkData();
View_BuildingModule_UC010_BusinessPark_Wizard_GetBusinessParkPortfolioManagerData vwBusParkPortfolioMngr = new View_BuildingModule_UC010_BusinessPark_Wizard_GetBusinessParkPortfolioManagerData();

vwBusPark.Where.BusinessParkID.Value = businessParkID;
vwBusParkPortfolioMngr.Where.BusinessParkID.Value = businessParkID;

if (vwBusPark.Query.Load())
    dataSet.BusinessPark.Merge(vwBusPark.toDataTable(), true, System.Data.MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);
```

Comment: Those are some crazy class names...you should consider using the `var` keyword to save some typing

Comment: Should `toDataTable` be capitalized?

Comment: Nop, it works that way. Its in the SqlEntityClass of a framework called myGenerationDoodas

Comment: For now, I am still waiting another solution please, Slaks solution didnt work to me ;) thank you :)

Comment: You should be able to get an `IEnumerable<YourRow>`.  Explore the `GetBusinessParkPortfolioManagerData` class.

Comment: this works  IEnumerable<UC010_WizardStepBusinessParkDataSet.BusinessParkRow> row;
           , then what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try merging with

```
vwBusPark.Except(dataSet.BusinessPark, DataRowComparer<YourRow>.Default)
```

Comment: That's in `System.Core.dll` and `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll`

Comment: Already added those 2 dlls and it says it does not contain definition.

Comment: Does not contain what? What type is `BusinessPark`?

Comment: Its a typed datatable in a typed dataset.    public BusinessParkDataTable BusinessPark

Comment: and View_BuildingModule_UC010_BusinessPark_Wizard_GetBusinessParkData its a generated class using mygeneration doodas, based on a view.

Comment: What error message do you get? Does the DataTable class inherit `TypedTableBase<T>`?

Comment: Error 6 '.View_BuildingModule_UC010_BusinessPark_Wizard_GetBusinessParkData' does not contain a definition for 'Except' and no extension method 'Except' accepting a first argument of type 'View_BuildingModule_UC010_BusinessPark_Wizard_GetBusinessParkData' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ark_Wizard\BusinessParkWizardBL.cs 41 17 Ceusters.REFM.BuildingModule.Business
Yes it looks like it inherit from that one: public partial class BusinessParkDataTable : global::System.Data.TypedTableBase<BusinessParkRow>

Comment: You need to get an `IEnumerable<BusinessParkDataRow>`, perhaps by calling `ToDataTable`.

Comment: I have no idea.  That depends on your GetBusinessParkData class.